# Twitter authorization via oauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter

Been following this [tutorial](http://cbpowell.wordpress.com/2011/03/17/twitter-oauth-and-ruby-on-rails-integrated-cookbook-style-in-the-console-updated-for-twitter-1-0/).

Is there a way to "allow access" without having to browse to the url: http://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=your_request_token_from_above?

Is there a way I can authorize a user via the oauth gem in console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way oauth is implements demands that you send the user to twitter, so that the user could give the authentication details to twitter and then authorize your access request (for your application).

if you want to skip the callback url and all that. You should look at [xAuth](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/xauth). With xAuth the you could provide the username and the password and get a token through the API, with no callback URLs or what so ever.

Here [some](http://www.cocoalife.net/2011/01/post_864.html) example of how to use xAuth with ruby.

Comment: What about for Facebook? Can xAuth be used for the FB API? So far, on google, no useful results